# Problems about checking for prime number in a Windows Form app

Tags: c#, primes

My app is to test for prime number. First time I enter a prime number, the result is `true` and number is displayed to user. But second time, the `prime number check` is not functioning as expected. Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label3.Text = textBox1.Text;

    float a = (float)Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

    if (check_Number(ref a) == true)
    {
        ResultCheck.Text = "Input Number is Prime";
    }
    else if (check_Number(ref a) == false)
    {
        ResultCheck.Text = "Input Number is not Prime";
    }
}
```

Comment: please post code for `check_Number` or at least the declaration

Comment: "app is not running"?

Answer (score 1):

here is an example program that uses trial division.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PrimeCheck
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = textBox1.Text; 

        double testthis = 0;
        if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out testthis))
        {
            if (CheckForPrime(testthis))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("prime time!!");
            }
        }
    }

    bool CheckForPrime(double number)
    {//there are better ways but this is cheap and easy for an example

        bool result = true;//assume we are prime until we can prove otherwise

        for (double d = 2; d < number; d++)
        {
            if (number % d == 0) 
            {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @user3555485 if it answered your question please mark